# ServiceLocatorFactoryBean equivalent in Quarkus

Tags: quarkus

Is there one? If not how to achieve the same result?

I want to be able to inject one bean, have that bean implement a method that returns a predefined singleton bean according to String or enum id passed to the method.

There are many examples on the web but in pseudo code it boils down to:

```
enum Discount { MINUS_10, MINUS_20 }

interface DiscountStrategy { Int apply() }

@Component(Discount.MINUS_10)
class DiscountMinus10 implements DiscountStrategy {...}

@Component(Discount.MINUS_20)
class DiscountMinus20 implements DiscountStrategy {...}

@Bean
class BusinessLogic {
    DiscountFactory factory; // ServiceLocatorFactoryBean 

    calculate(Product product) {
       Discount discount = product.getDiscount()
       DiscountStrategy strategy = factory.getComponent(discount)
       Int value = strategy.apply()
       ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you trying to achieve? Thanks